# Move pointer to object from one list to another without destroying object

Tags: c++, list, pointers

Consider this code:

```
transferPtr(Node *moveMe, list<Node*> &listA, list<Node*> &listB) {
    // How do I remove moveMe from A?
    listB.push_back(moveMe);
}
```

Assume the pointer `moveMe` (pointer to a Node, or any object) is in `listA`, but we're only given the pointer, not an iterator. We're moving `moveMe` out of `listA` and into `listB`.

How do I remove `moveMe` from `listA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the list splice function you can avoid the memory allocation for the list node.
Using remove() would have to search the list anyway.

```
list<Node*>::iterator i = std::find(listA.begin(), listA.end(), moveMe);
if (i != listA.end()) {
    listB.splice(listB.end(), listA, i);
}
```

If the pointer can exist more than 1 time in list A then you'll need to use something like the following, however your STL implementation may not do this as efficiently as you'd hope.

```
list<Node*>::iterator i = std::remove(listA.begin(), listA.end(), moveMe);
if (i != listA.end()) {
    listB.splice(listB.end(), listA, i, listA.end());
}
```

Comment: This is great because I can use it to move only the first instance of moveMe if there are more than one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
listA.remove(moveMe);
```

should do it.

Since you only remove the pointer, the object will not be destroyed.